# How do I represent a set of "has and belongs to many" self-relation items in HTML?

Tags: html, markup, directed-acyclic-graphs

I'm working on a Ruby on Rails system which has a `Project` table with a `has_and_belongs_to_many` relation to *itself* (cyclic relations are not possible). In this way, a project can be part of more than one other project, which is very useful, and a killer feature of the legacy system the new application is based on. I need a way to display all of the projects on a single page with their `name`, `short_name`, and other simple properties. Each project must be shown in relation to each of their parents (duplicate entries are fine), and each property value must be aligned *by the browser* with each other property (none of that "static width" muck which breaks all the time). Projects must also be collapsible, although I suspect this is not relevant for the solution.

The current solution is similar to the [How do I present a tree in an HTML table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/945460/how-do-i-present-a-tree-in-an-html-table) solution: Use a `<table>` and implement a "tree-like" structure in the leftmost column by using CSS `padding-left`. The full parent-child relations are kept by storing the parent project IDs for each project. Because this is not semantic markup, it's difficult to handle the resulting table with JavaScript. If you want to collapse a node, you have to traverse each `<tr>` after the collapsed one until you find one on the same level, rather than just deleting the list of children. Also, several projects are shown more than once

**Is there a semantic way to represent such a data structure in HTML** (any version), without sacrificing all ability to style it sanely? A list of tables won't align properly, and mixing lists with tables is not possible, as far as I know.

I'm not tagging with `ruby` or `ruby-on-rails` because the programming language is not relevant for the task, only to explain the structure of the existing system.

Answer (score 0):

you can mix lists with tables...your post is a little difficult to take in, im sure a drawing would help but from what i can take away from it, i'll try and help if I can

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <% obj1.each do |o1| %>
    <td>
      <ul id="tree_<%= o1.id %>">
        <% obj2.each do |o2| %>
          <li><%= o2.name %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </td>
    <% end %>
  </tr>
</table>
```

then you can just hide the column of the specified ul.tree

maybe I've misunderstood your needs, but i hope that helps! :)

go rails!!

Comment: Once you're in the `<ul>`, how do you create the `<tr>`s for the child objects? I don't think this is possible.

Comment: well you dont need to, you use the ul to control your rows, the table itself only creates the column structure for you

Comment: ie...each <li> constitutes a cell of a row replacing the need for <tr>

Comment: But each row has more than one column - How do I make those align?

Comment: each column (<ul>) would be in it's own <td>, giving your a series of columns.  Each cell of your row is represented in the <li>...i dont know what data it is your displaying specifically, so i dont know how one cell of a row should relate to the next, but if they need to be inline you can style the <li> to accomodate the data.

Comment: I think I see. The graph is of arbitrary depth, and any object can be a child of one or more other objects, with only two exceptions: The top-level object has no parents, and there can be no loops. Therefore the structure needs to be recursive, not just two levels deep.

Comment: this will give you a column based table as opposed to a row based table, ie, you can hide columns (<ul>) easily as opposed to conventionally hiding rows easily (<tr>)..thats not to say that the content of the <li>'s can contain other tables or lists. you can take it as many levels deep as you need to, you just have to have your styles set up to accomodate those needs

Comment: Can you show an actual static HTML page like this? I'm having trouble wrapping my head around how this could be used for a multi-level DAG.

Comment: I was envisioning something like http://bit.ly/HVWNMe as opposed to a DAG like http://bit.ly/HVWNMe, I didnt notice your dag tag and it wasnt mentioned in your OP otherwise lol depending on what your looking for i might not even try and do this in html, but use svg to render your graph with soemthing like http://mbostock.github.com/d3/